# FrontEnd Magento Hello World Not Working

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Please help with this newbie magento tutorial, I've been struggling with this for 2 days..
Using XAMPP 1.7 and magento 1.9.1... I already create the magento directory & file structure like this:

```
  -htdocs  
    -magento
      -app
        -code
          -local
            -Practice
              -Mymodule
                -controllers
                  IndexController.php
                -etc
                  config.xml
        -etc
          -modules
            Practice_Mymodule.xml
```

And this is the content of file **Practice_Mymodule.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Practice_Mymodule>
      <active>true</active>
      <codepool>local</codepool>
    </Practice_Mymodule>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**config.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Practice_Mymodule>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Practice_Mymodule>
  </modules>

  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <mymodule>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Practice_Mymodule</module>
          <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
        </args>
      </mymodule>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

**IndexController.php** :

```
<?php
  class Practice_Mymodule_IndexController
    extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
      /**
      * General report action  
      */
      public function indexAction() {
        echo '<h1>Hello Magento!</h1>';
      }
    }
?>
```

I already follow the tutorial step-by-step, but I always get a 404 page not found when it should have been

## Hello Magento!

This is the url I'm trying to access: **http://localhost/magento/index.php/mymodule**

Can anyone pointout where have I gone wrong? And how to fix this to work properly?

Comment: As Qaisar Satti said yes it seems there is a class name problem ion your controller.class name should be like your packagename_yourmodulename_yourcontroller

Comment: yes, that too, and I also misstype coolpool, it suppose tobe codePool. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Practice_Mymodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Practice_Mymodule>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Practice_Mymodule>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Practice_Mymodule>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Practice_Mymodule>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <mymodule>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Practice_Mymodule</module>
            <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
          </args>
      </mymodule>
    </routers>

  </frontend>

</config>
```

**Practice/Mymodule/controlle/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Practice_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function IndexAction() {

      echo '<h1>Hello Magento!</h1>';

    }
}
```

tried this it is working. i tested by myself